# Securing an individual column in Cassandra

Tags: security, cassandra

We want our developers to be able to query our Cassandra tables in production (for trouble shooting and other analysis).  However, we don't want them seeing secure data like e-mail addresses and names of customers.

I've thought about creating a MATERIALIZED VIEW in Cassandra that selects then entire table except for the sensitive columns.  Then I could grant developers SELECT access on the view, but not the main table.

Is that the best way to secure a column in Cassandra?

Someone else I know suggested just encrypting those columns using a data-encrypt feature that our application already has.  We would encrypt a field into a string of Hex codes before giving it to Cassandra to store.  That would have an added benefit of encrypting the data at-rest in the Cassandra sstable and commit log.  BUT if that field is encrypted, then Cassandra can't see the true value of that field, and that could be a big problem for ORDER BY or other CQL comparison functions.

How are most people securing data in Cassandra?  :)

Comment: Aren't your developers the people that wrote the code to push the data into Cassandra in the first place? If they have access when inserting the data into the database you have the same risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one right answer to this today.  In addition to encryption or views, another approach would be to basically normalize the data, and store the sensitive data in a separate table and/or keyspace.

[DataGuise](http://dataguise)'s DgSecure is a commercial product which offers masking capabilities for NoSQL, including Cassandra.  There seems to be little information other than [press releases](http://www.marketwired.com/press-release/dataguise-announces-new-sensitive-data-monitoring-solution-that-accelerates-breach-detection-2104970.htm) available about it.